# Passing inline arguments to shell script being executed on HDFS

Tags: shell-script, command-line, hadoop

I am running a shell script stored on HDFS (so that it can be recognized by my oozie workflow). to run this script I am using

```
hadoop fs -cat script.sh |exec sh
```

However I need to pass inline arguments to the script. On the CLI I would simply do this with

```
./script.sh arg1
```

Then echo the varaiable with $1. I am trying to figure out how I would do the same with a script stored in HDFS

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like the following; it uses a separate invocation of hadoop fs cat (in a process substitution) to retrieve each file and present it to script.sh as a file name to open for reading.

```
 # Adjust the hdfs: URLs as necessary
 hadoop fs -cat hdfs://path_to_script/sample.sh | exec bash  \
  <(hadoop fs -cat hdfs://param1) \
  <(hadoop fs -cat hdfs://param2) \
  <(hadoop fs -cat hdfs://param3) \
  <(hadoop fs -cat hdfs://param4)
```

If script.sh already knows that how to read from hdfs, then

```
  hadoop fs -cat hdfs://path_to_script/script.sh | exec bash -s param1 param2 param3 param4
```

may be sufficient. The -s option tells bash to read the script from standard input, so that it doesn't mistake param1 as the name of the script to run.